# Swift Package Manager: "multiple targets named..."

Tags: swift, dependency-management, swift-package-manager, kitura

I'm trying to build a server-side Swift web application.  The foundational framework for my app will be [Kitura](https://www.kitura.io) from IBM.  Additionally, I would also like to make use of the [aws-sdk-swift](https://github.com/noppoMan/aws-sdk-swift) framework for calls in to AWS.  However, when I declare both libraries as dependencies in my `Package.swift` file, I get an error saying:

> 'Kitura-net'
>   /Volumes/Untitled/SwiftDev/MyApp/.build/checkouts/Kitura-net.git--7410958935072501107:
>   error: multiple targets named 'CHTTPParser'

If I comment out the `aws-sdk-swift` dependency, everything works fine.  If I uncomment it and comment out the `Kitura` dependency, everything works fine.  But clearly there is a conflict between them on CHTTPParser.  My question is, how do I resolve it?  I've never seen this error before, and a quick Google search turned up nothing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing the error because both Kitura and aws-sdk-swift have a different dependency called CHTTPParser. Kitura requires https://github.com/IBM-Swift/CHTTPParser, but aws-sdk-swift indirectly requires https://github.com/ZewoGraveyard/CHTTPParser through depending on [aws-sdk-swift-core](https://github.com/noppoMan/aws-sdk-swift-core) then [Prorsum](https://github.com/noppoMan/Prorsum). Swift Package Manager can't currently deal with [dependency naming collisons](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1168).

It looks like the aws-sdk-swift dependency has been deprecated (it's in Zewo's 'Graveyard'), but [this issue](https://github.com/noppoMan/aws-sdk-swift-core/issues/24) exists in its sub-dependency which looks like the author is intending to move away from Prorsum, which directly requires the deprecated dependency.

It's unfortunate that you've hit the problem, but as there's no way for SPM to deal with this currently you'll either have to find an alternative to aws-sdk-swift, wait for it to be changed to not use the out-of-date dependency or try forking the repos and making the changes yourself!